# Configuring Springboot-Gadle with Nodejs

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, npm

Please pardon me for showing too much code, I'd show more not less

I have ran in the following problem while trying to configure build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.moowork.node" version "1.3.1"
}

group = 'com.traveling.owl'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

node {
    version = '12.16.1'
    download = true
    workDir = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/reactjs/nodejs")
    npmWorkDir = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/reactjs/npm")
    nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/reactjs")
}

task npmInstallDependencies(type: NpmTask) {
    dependsOn 'npmSetup'
    execOverrides {
        it.ignoreExitValue = true
        it.workingDir = 'src/main/reactjs'
    }
    args = ['install']
}

task npmBuild(type: NpmTask) {
    dependsOn 'npmInstallDependencies'
    execOverrides {
        it.workingDir = 'src/main/reactjs'
    }
    args = ['run', 'build']
}

task copyBuild(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn 'npmBuild'
    from "$projectDir/src/main/reactjs/build"
    into "$buildDir/resources/main/static"
}

processResources {
    dependsOn 'copyBuild'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

This (`gradle build`) gives the following error msg:

```
xecution failed for task ':nodeSetup'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration55'.
   > Could not find org.nodejs:node:v12.16.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://nodejs.org/dist/vv12.16.1/ivy.xml
```

But when I tpye `node -v` its output is:
`v12.16.1.`

It seems like npm doesn't see the version of node installed?

I've tried to reinstall npm and it didn't solve my issue

OSX 10.14.6 Mojave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is reported to be an incompatibility between Gradle 6+ and moowork node plugin for Gradle.

To solve it you have two options:

1) Change the property **download** to **false** and install the version of node required manually. Your gradle node config would look like:

```
node {
    version = '12.6.1'
    npmVersion = '6.10.2'
    distBaseUrl = 'https://nodejs.org/dist'
    download = false
    workDir = file("${project.buildDir}/nodejs")
    npmWorkDir = file("${project.buildDir}/npm")
    yarnWorkDir = file("${project.buildDir}/yarn")
    nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}")
}
```

2) Switch to a different Gradle - Node, plugin. This is explained here: https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/issues/292#issuecomment-562848790

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm switching to a different plugin, I'll close my question